# How to verify email from server

Tags: android, email-validation

I am new to android.I simply have a text field where the user enters their email address.I have an a list of email verified at my backend.Now when the user enters email.I should first check whether email is verified in backend or not.If the email is verified that the user gets access to next activity else not.

```
public class Ongoing extends Fragment {


    Button proceed;
    EditText email;
    TextView surveyTitle;
    String success;

    private static final String url="http://192.168.0.123/survey/public/api/verifyemail";

    public Ongoing() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ongoing, container, false);
        surveyTitle= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.surveyTitle);
        email = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.email);
        proceed= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.proceed);
        proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isConnected()) {

                    String emailAddress = email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

                    if (emailAddress.matches("")) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please fill up all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        if (emailAddress.matches(emailPattern)) {
                            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.0.123/survey/public/api/verifyemail");
                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
            try {
                success = json.getString("success");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(success.equals("Email verified. Please proceed with survey"))
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wait For a moment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Somebody please help me.

Comment: What is your problem/error?

Comment: @Robin neither any error nor any solution

Answer (score 0):

Here you have coded,

```
try {
     success = json.getString("success");
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So you kept success key. Make it one of two value according to logic. If email found / verified response will send,

> "success"="success"

And if not found / verified,

> "success"="error" // error or any string message to identify user email not found.

If you get success only then change activity